# How to render text in component form <text /> in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display text in the form of react component inside react app.

When I tried to render it, it gives me `not defined` error, which is understandable.

```
import React from 'react';
import HeaderClass from './Header.css';
import logo from '../../Assets/Images/logo.jpg'
const Header = () => {
    return(
    <div className="header-wrapper">
            <p className="logo__tagline"> <text />  </p>
        <img className="App__logo" src={logo} alt="Name" />
    </div>
    )
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Could you include your code to the question please?

Comment: Your question is to vague to answer without seeing your code.

Comment: as commented above your question is vague and show some code

Comment: Hi sorry guys, just added code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do?
But if i understand correct you could do like this:

In the text file:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'; // So it doesn't create a unnecessary node element. **Only available in react 16+

export const Text = () => <Fragment>Your text here</Fragment>;
```

and then you can bring in the text element and use it in your code:

```
import React from 'react';
import HeaderClass from './Header.css';
import logo from '../../Assets/Images/logo.jpg'
import { Text } from './Text'

const Header = () => {
  return(
   <div className="header-wrapper">
      <p className="logo__tagline"> <Text />  </p>
      <img className="App__logo" src={logo} alt="Name" />
   </div>
  )
};

export default Header;
```

Maybe i have misunderstood the question but i don't know why you would want to do this.

Comment: Hi @tygar, text is not a element. Text is just normal text for example Company name. But I want to display that text (company name) surrounded by `< />`.

Comment: Don’t think you can do that because the arrow brackets usually imply a element. If you are just wanting to distinguish the text for some reason you could wrap them in brackets and quotes like this `{‘Your text here’}` place that Inside you p element